# Sound is not played on receiving local notification in react-native after update to 0.30

Tags: ios, react-native

I am creating a mobile app using `react-native` where I schedule local notifications which play a sound when the notification is fired. I am using `PushNotificationIOS` API in `react-native` to handle local notification in `iOS`. I have been using `react-native` version `0.24` till now and the sound use to play as expected. I recently updated to latest version `0.30` and the sound doesn't play now on receiving notification. I am not sure what is wrong as nothing has been changed w.r.t. playing sound using `PushNotificationIOS` since `0.24`. I have confirmed that:

- The sound file is present in the Xcode project
- It is present in the `Copy Bundle Resources` in Xcode
- The sound file is actually present in the app by playing the sound file using `react-native-sound` package in the simulator
- The soundName is set correctly in the local notification. I printed the `notification.getSound()` and got the right name.

I even tried with playing the default sound by setting the `soundName` to `default` but still no sound. Below is how I am scheduling the local notification:

```
PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    fireDate: time,
    alertBody: alertBody,
    soundName: 'default',
    userInfo: info,
    category: category
  });
```

**index.ios.js file**

```
class TestLocalNotification extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions()
  }

  scheduleLocalNotification = () => {
    console.log('Scheduling local notification')
    PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
      fireDate: Date.now() + 60000,
      alertBody: 'Notificaiton',
      soundName: 'default'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.scheduleLocalNotification}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem can be reproduced by following steps

- Create a new project by giving command `react-native init TestLocalNotification`
- Copy the above code for the component in the `index.ios.js` file
- Import `PushNotificaionIOS` and `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native`

Run the app. Click the text `Welcome to React Native` and go to home screen by pressing `shift + cmd + h` . Observe that a local notification after a minute but no sound is played.

Please advice on how I can debug and fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I am using v0.37 right now and the sound plays as expected there. Sometimes, I have observed that the sound doesn't play on the Simulator but plays on the actual device. So, you may want to check that as well.